# DiscriminatorMap Persistence

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Having a small little issue with Symfony2 and Doctrine2 with regards to persisting an object with a discriminator map column. I've been googling for hours but just can't find the answer.

The code I'm using is below - I'm trying to persist a new user, and based on it's "user type" (as declared in the form), the new Teacher/Student/Whatever.

If someone is kind enough to help me out, could you also please explain WHY you are doing what you are doing? Just so I can make sense out of all this ORM stuff, which is quite new to me.

Here is my SystemUser class

```
/**
 * SystemUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\Repository\SystemUserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"0" = "SystemUser", "1" = "SchoolAdmin", "2" = "Teacher", "3" = "Student", "4" = "Guardian"})
 */
class SystemUser implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="is_active")
     */
    protected $isActive;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="date")
     */
    protected $birthDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="cellphone", type="string", length=10)
     */
    protected $cellphone;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     */
    protected $roles;

    /**
     *
     *
     *
     *
     * Begin methods
     *
     *
     *
     */


    public function __construct() {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

... Other methods left out as they all seem to work fine. Note that there is no explicit column for the discriminator, though it still generates it in the schema through the annotation. Is this correct?

Now my FormType...

```
class UserFormType extends AbstractType {
    private $router;
    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->setAction($this->router->generate('register_new_user'))
            ->add('username', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('birth_date', 'date', array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
            ))
            ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'first_name' => 'password',
                'second_name' => 'confirm',
                'type' => 'password',
            ))
            ->add('cellphone', 'text', array(
                'max_length' => 10,
                'invalid_message' => 'A phone number must be exactly 10 characters long',
            ));

            //Add additional stuff here like access role, status, account active, etc...
            $builder->add('roles', null, array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'label' => 'Role'
                    ))
                    ->add('is_active', 'checkbox', array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'label' => 'Active'
                    ))
                                    //Here is where I get the issue mentioned below
                    ->add('discr', 'choice', array(
                        'choices' => array(
                            '1' => 'School Administrator',
                            '2' => 'Teacher',
                            '3' => 'Student',
                            '4' => 'Guardian'
    ,                   ),
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'label' => 'User Type'
                    ));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SCWORX\MainBundle\Entity\SystemUser',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'user_form';
    }
}
```

Where I add the discr choice field, I get the following error:

```
Neither the property "discr" nor one of the methods "getDiscr()", "isDiscr()", "hasDiscr()", "__get()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\SystemUser".
```

And finally, the Registration Form is here...

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType {
    private $router;
    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->setAction($this->router->generate('create_user'))
                ->add('user', 'user_form')
                ->add('submit', 'submit');

    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'user_registration';
    }
}
```

I should probably note that both forms have been registered as services.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In your SystemUser entity class you don't have a property called 'discr'.  Your current annotation is saying, when my 'discr' property contains these different values (the ones you have listed in DiscriminatorMap), the entity changes into these different types, SchoolAdmin, Teacher, etc.

So, you need to add the discr property to SystemUser, then when you use that in your form, the value entered will be saved in that property on the object and your code will know what 'type' of SystemUser that object is!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added `protected $discr` in the SystemUser class, along with its getters (`getDiscr()`) and setter (`setDiscr()`), ran doctrine:generate:entities Bundle. Now I don't get that error anymore, but it's not persisting the selected value to the DB. Any ideas? EDIT - I didn't annotate the new $discr propery as doctrine was complaining about it being a duplicate - is that correct?

Comment: Did you add the getters/setters yourself, or did you let the generate:entities command add them for you?

Comment: Is there a discr field in the db?

Comment: Yeah, I assume thats just coming from the annotation?